# IE8 Doesn't Show Background Images on IIS

Tags: html, css, iis

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="js">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>| TheProfessional Theme</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .et-custom-list ul
        {
            list-style: none !important;
            list-style-image: none !important;
            padding-left: 0 !important;
            margin: 0 !important;
            line-height: 26px;
        }
        .et-custom-list ul li
        {
            padding-left: 28px !important;
            margin: 5px 0 !important;
            list-style: none !important;
            position: relative;
        }
        .et-custom-list ul li:before
        {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 0;
            background: url(https://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/TheProfessional/wp-content/themes/TheProfessional/epanel/shortcodes/images/shortcodes-sprite.png) no-repeat -74px -2px;
            width: 22px;
            height: 18px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="et-custom-list">
        <ul>
            <li>list item 1</li>
            <li>list item 2
                <ul>
                    <li>list item 1</li>
                    <li>list item 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>list item 3</li>
            <li>list item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When saved as a HTML file on my desktop, it works in all browsers. When I move the file to a server (IIS) it works in all browsers apart from II8. Is there any reason why it suddenly stops working in IE8 on IIS?

Now a colleague has showed me that it doesn't work in IE7 on desktop either

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your background urls with double quotes (`"`):

```
background: url("https://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/TheProfessional/wp-content/themes/TheProfessional/epanel/shortcodes/images/shortcodes-sprite.png") no-repeat -74px -2px;
```